# What is Bower private repository? How do i create my own private Bower repository?

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

I have been searching in the internet for creating a private bower repository for past two days, but i couldn't find any step by step tutorials and the available resource is really confusing.
Can anyone help me, how to create my own bower repository?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bower registry server](https://github.com/bower/registry#installation) in the official bower github.  the directions for setting it up are short, though it requires a PostgreSQL server lying around.  Another registry server is documented [here](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/08/04/How-to-host-a-private-bower-registry/)

Actually using it will require [setting](http://bower.io/docs/config/) `registry.search` to the site served above, and you might also want to set `shorthandResolver`, and `strictSsl` to agree with your build environment.

The 'official' bower config specs, are not, as of this writing, up to date with bower as it exists in npm; The following will show you what settings are available, and if you're changes have had an effect:

```
node -e "console.log(require('bower-config').read())"
```

(I have not actually done all of these things yet; and will probably have to create a filesystem only registry if bower resolving is to become part of our build)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower

It provides a private Bower server and also allows you to use public packages as a 'fallback' (much like you might do with Nexus or Artifactory in the Maven world), effectively turning your private Bower repo into a proxy for public Bower as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of the [Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.0](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/04/06/spring-into-the-future-nexus-repository-manager-3-0-release/) you can host your [private bower registries](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bower.html) in your own datacenter as well as proxy remote ones

Same applies for npm so you have the full stack improved from installing bower via npm and onwards.